# Gradually change colour of a bitmap?

Tags: java, android

I've got several bitmaps on the screen that gradually need to change colours depending on values they are set. I've looked into LightingColorFilter, PorterDuffColorFilter and ColorMatrix but the problem is the colours change constantly (tens of times a second and many objects). The problem with the 2 above is they create memory leaks and performance problems.

Can anyone suggest a way of gradually changing the colour of the bitmap (without creating a new bitmap or storing the canvas temporary? - also performance hinders). I've looked around and it doesn't seem possible without OpenGL (Something I have no clue about).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that for the effects you are looking for at the speed you requiring will only be achievable with OpenGL or Renderscript if you are willing to limit yourself to Android 3.0 (Honeycomb) and up.

One project to look at is the Android port of GPUImage

https://github.com/cyberagent-jp/android-gpuimage

And see if you can reuse the prebuilt filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an image with limited number of colors (say 256) using an index of colors, and then modify the colors of the index. That is fast enough.

This is [pallette animation](http://java.sys-con.com/node/35750). This example uses Thread.sleeps for the animation itself, but that you can replace with correct animation and progress logic.